# Group/sort by multiple criteria

Tags: templating, group

I have some users:

```
{% set people = craft.users({ 
groupId:    '1',
order:      'lastname ASC' 
})
```

And two lightswitch fields associated: **isLeadership** and **isActive**.

This code groups users by isLeadership.

```
  {% set peopleByLeadership = people|group('isLeadership')|reverse %}
  {% for isLeadership, thePeople in peopleByLeadership  %}
    {% for person in thePeople %}
      {{ person.lastname }} etc...
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

How do I group people first by 'isLeadership' and then by 'isActive'?

Results should be:

- Person 1 (leadership, active)
- Person 2 (active)
- Person 3...10 (not
  active)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple columns to the [`orderBy` parameter](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/users.html#orderby) like so:

```
{% set people = craft.users().groupId(1).orderBy('isLeadership DESC, isActive DESC, lastname ASC').all() %}

{% for person in people %}
    {{ person.lastname }}
{% endfor %}
```

Theoretically that should give you your people sorted by leadership status, then active status, and then last name.

Comment: Hmmm...thought I tried that already, but I'll give it another go. Thanks.

Comment: @jalen-daveport: This does not return the expected results - am getting folks where isActive = true scattered within the output, not sorted to the beginning. To clarify, both the isLeadership and isActive fields are lightswitch fields. Could I be missing something?